# Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64'

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I have created a nuget package and published to Azure. When I add the package to another project it fails with the following error:

[image: Error Description]

I followed the same process for every other nuget package without issues. Any tips?

Comment: Does this package could install on another project successful or not? And other nuget package that you installed correctly are all custom package or come from nuget.org? If possible, please share this specific package here and tell us what project type do you used to install this package.

Comment: Did you found more error details (output window, ....)?

Comment: Can you share more detailed steps for this question?